# Java junit test: "Cannot access Matcher"

Tags: java, testing, junit

Writing test cases for program and I'm trying to test for an expected exception.

In the testStatus method, the line

> thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);

I get an "error: cannot access Matcher". I'm lost as to why and I can't find anything online about it. This is a school project but it's a senior level course so no need to be vague. Learning syntax is the least of my concern. We won't be tested on that. We're graded more on the quality of our test, not how we wrote the test.

And yes, the commented line also breaks. Should that line be before or after the code (I would guess before)

Edit: Also, when running the main program, it does in fact throw the exception properly. I just need to get junit to recognize that.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.Rule;


public class TaxCalculatorTest {


@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();   



@Test
public void testStatus(){

  //thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);

  TaxCalculator taxes = new TaxCalculator();
  taxes.calculateTax(0, 40000);

  thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TaxCalculatorTest.class);      

}
}
```

Comment: Please show the full error message and stack trace. If you run the test via the given main method, you won't see any output.

Comment: I'm stupid. I didn't notice the line below that says "class file for org.hamcrest.Matcher not found" I have the hamcrest jar file in the correct directory. I guess I need to import it.

Comment: You need to put it on the class path. How this is done depends on what your development environment is.

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking but you could just pass this as a parameter to the `@Test` annotation, like this: `@Test( expected = IllegalArgumentException.class )`